# trouble with Vue.js in Spring MVC jsp pages

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, vue.js

I am trying to add view to my jsp files, I am using the cdn to add view to my spring mvc app. I have a very basic setup and for whatever reason the msg attribute that I have added on the data object just shows as {{ msg }} instead of the actual message.

header.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link  href="./css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="app">
            <div class="container">
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@include file = "header.jsp" %>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>This is an example</h1>
        {{ msg }}
    </div>
        <a href="./reviews">reviews</a>
        <a href="./hotel_requests">hotel requests</a>
<%@include file = "footer.jsp" %>
```

footer.jsp:

```
            </div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
let app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        msg:'Hello Vue!'
    }
})
```

this is all being done as part of a spring mvc app. I have been online trying to find solutions but it doesn't seem like there are none.... or the scenario doesn't apply to me. I am using Apache tomcat version 9, just in case the server has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the script tag that referenced my external JavaScript file was supposed to be put at the bottom of the document. More specifically right before the end tag of the body (). It somehow made a difference...